# Best way to implement content type specific search?

Tags: search, content-type

I am planning on rolling my own web part where users can select a content type and it will generate search fields based on the columns.  Am I right to write my own or is there a better way to do this that I am unaware of?

Somewhat related to this question:

[Can I get the source for the out-of-the-box web parts in SharePoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/can-i-get-the-source-for-the-out-of-the-box-web-parts-in-sharepoint-2010)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enumerate the content types in a site collection using the object model, and then for each Content Type you can get the Fields to see what fields should be displayed.

Populate a dropdown box for content types, and handle SelectedIndexChanged event handler to populate a second dropdown box with the Fields' titles found in the FieldLinks you get for the selected Content Type.

Useful Links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.contenttypes.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype.fields.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx

Comment: I would want to use the FieldLinks and not the Fields member of the SPContentType?

Comment: Well spotted, I'm used to adding fields to content types programmatically, force of habit. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Just to complement James' answer, I would make something that can enumerate only specific content types, but allow the user to choose (i.e. create a custom toolpart)

Comment: Going a step further from Neil's complement, let have you pick a content type and let it only show the child content types. Dude, you're giving us ideas ;)